Universal method of combining 2D graphics into 3D graphics
Show can combine either several 2D graphics or several 3D but can not combine 2D graphics with 3D graphics.
While in principle there should be no such limitation, every 2D graphics with coordinates x, y can be embedded into 3D graphics with coordinates x, y, z so that 2D graphic lie in plane xy of 3D space.
Here are three examples how it can be done but the method is not universal, what works for one 2D function may not work for others.
So the task is to create generalization of Show that would be able to combine any 2D with 3D.
ContourPlot[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, (x + 1/2)^2 + y^2 == 1/4}, {x, -1, 
  1}, {y, -1, 1}]

Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Sphere[]}], % /. 
   Graphics -> Graphics3D /. 
  GraphicsComplex[x_, y___] :> 
   GraphicsComplex[Append[#, 0] & /@ x, y]]



ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> (#^2 < #2 &)]

Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Sphere[]}], % /. 
   Graphics -> Graphics3D /. 
  GraphicsComplex[x_, y___] :> 
   GraphicsComplex[Append[#, 0] & /@ x, y]]



Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]

Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], 
   Sphere[]}], % /. Graphics -> Graphics3D /. 
   Line[x___] :> Line[Append[#, 0] & /@ x] /. 
  HoldPattern[PlotRange -> x_] -> PlotRange -> Automatic]




This is nice approach (+1). Some plots we can combine with Inset[] as well.

A simpler an more general solution is to replace all 2D coordinates by 3D coordinates like:
rule = {x_Real, y_Real} -> {x, y, 0};

With this, your examples:
ContourPlot[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, (x + 1/2)^2 + y^2 == 1/4}, {x, -1, 
   1}, {y, -1, 1}];
Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Sphere[]}], 
 t /. Graphics -> Graphics3D /. rule]


ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  RegionFunction -> (#^2 < #2 &)];
Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], 
   Sphere[]}], % /. Graphics -> Graphics3D /.  
   Graphics -> Graphics3D /. rule]


Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];
Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], 
   Sphere[]}], % /. Graphics -> Graphics3D /. rule /. 
  HoldPattern[PlotRange -> x_] -> PlotRange -> Automatic]



But your rule is not selective enough. It may replace something else than a coordinate. For example PlotLabel -> {0.1, 0.3} would be replaced by PlotLabel -> {0.1, 0.3, 0}. But there can be much more serious cases when it will case an error. Also using HoldPattern[PlotRange -> x_] -> PlotRange -> Automatic in third example shows it is not universal and should be adapted differently for each 2D function.

Does not work with StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}] or ArrayPlot[{{1, 0, 0, 0.3}, {1, 1, 0, 0.3}, {1, 0, 1, 0.7}}].

Anyway (+1) since it works in many cases.

StreamPlot is a case when the rule is not selective enough and it replaces Arrowheads[{{x, y}}] with Arrowheads[{{x, y, 0}}] which cause an error.
